# MySQL `EXPLAIN` says DEPENDENT QUERY even though no correlation exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have what should be a straightforward query:

```
DELETE FROM schema_a.table_a 
WHERE column_a = 'VALUE_A' AND column_b NOT IN (SELECT id FROM schema_b.table_b)
```

But this query is very slow. Running EXPLAIN reveals that the subquery is of type "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY", meaning it will run as many times as there are rows in the outer query. But why is this happening? I don't see any relation between the inner query and the outer query.

The interesting thing is that even I replace `DELETE FROM` with `SELECT * FROM`, the inner query is of type "SUBQUERY" -> i.e. this will run very fast.

I'd like to know why the difference in `EXPLAIN` for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this is happening. I need to set an alias for both the tables. If I do that, then the query becomes a lot faster and is not DEPENDENT SUBQUERY anymore.

```
DELETE tbl_a FROM schema_a.table_a tbl_a
WHERE tbl_a.column_a = 'VALUE_A'
AND tbl_a.column_b NOT IN (SELECT tbl_b.id FROM schema_b.table_b tbl_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using **NOT EXISTS**:

```
DELETE FROM schema_a.table_a tbl_a
WHERE tbl_a.column_a = 'VALUE_A' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM schema_b.table_b tbl_b 
                WHERE tbl_b.id = tbl_a.id)
```